# React Hooks - useFetch generalization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, design-patterns, react-hooks

I have an api which provides me methods like:

1. searchUsersByUsername(username, limit)
2. getRandomPremiumUsers(limit)
3. getYoungUsers(maxAge, limit)

I am implementing a hook "useFetchUsers", which will provide an interface to access these methods.

This is my current code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
  searchUsersByUsername, 
  getRandomPremiumUsers,
  getRandomYoungUsers,
} from "../../services/firebase/api/users/search"
import { MAX_SEARCH_USERS_BY_USERNAME_TO_RETRIEVE } from "../../utils/search";

export const QUERIES = {
  "SEARCH_USERS_BY_USERNAME": searchUsersByUsername,
  "FETCH_RANDOM_PREMIUM_USERS": getRandomPremiumUsers,
  "FETCH_RANDOM_YOUNG_USERS": getRandomYoungUsers,
};

const defaultOptions = {
  query: QUERIES[0],
  username: "", // optional
  limit = MAX_SEARCH_USERS_BY_USERNAME_TO_RETRIEVE, // optional
};

export default function useFetchUsers(options = defaultOptions, deps) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(undefined);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const users = await options.query();
      setUsers(users);
    } catch(err) {
      setError(err);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(getUsers, deps);

  return {
    users,
    isLoading,
    error,
    getUsers
  }
}
```

The main problem I am facing, is that I don't know how to make this "interface" more flexible, in order to be able to pass arguments to my QUERY methods.

Also, my defaultOptions object doesn't need the fields "username" for the methods "getRandomPremiumUsers" and "getRandomYoungUsers".

Any ideas about how to fit the requirements following a similar abstraction?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here: `useEffect(getUsers, deps);` ?

Comment: Your question is so broad, try to check if you can use react-query in your project. 

Also, there are multiple ways to achieve it. Simply you can create methods to fetch the data and return it. So you can call via any means.

Comment: @SinanYaman to fetch when components mounts if necessary

Comment: @ChandraKumar I cannot use react-query.

Comment: I have also thought to create independent hooks for each method, but in some way, as they are related concepts, I think that abstracting everything in a single hook is a better idea.

Comment: It seems that you this "generalization" might cause some extra re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create methods and return

```js
export default function useFetchUsers() {
  const initialState = {
    payload: null,
    error: null,
    inFlight: false,
  };
  const [result, setResult] = useState(initialState);
  const searchUsersByUsername = () => {
    setResult({ payload: null, error: null, inFlight: true });
    try {
      const payload = fetch("api");
      setResult({ payload, error: null, inFlight: false });
    } catch (error) {
      setResult({ payload: null, error: null, inFlight: false });
    }
  };
  return {
    ...result,
    searchUsersByUsername,
  };
}
```

### Write an API helper that implements fetching logic

```
const api = {
  user: {
    searchUsersByUsername: (option) => {
      return fetch(option);
    },
    getRandomPremiumUsers: (option) => {
      return fetch(option);
    },
    getYoungUsers: (option) => {
      return fetch(option);
    },
  },
};

export default function useFetchUsers() {
  const initialState = {
    payload: null,
    error: null,
    inFlight: false,
  };
  const [result, setResult] = useState(initialState);
  
  const updateState = (fetcher, option) => {
    setResult({ payload: null, error: null, inFlight: true });
    try {
      const payload = fetcher(option);
      setResult({ payload, error: null, inFlight: false });
    } catch (error) {
      setResult({ payload: null, error: null, inFlight: false });
    }
  };
  return {
    ...result,
    updateState,
  };
}

function App() {
  const { updateState, payload } = useFetchUsers();
  return (
    <div
      onclick={() =>
        updateState(api.user.searchUsersByUsername, { username: 'name', limit: 10 })
      }
    >
      searchUsersByUsername
    </div>
  );
}
```

So depending upon your use case you can implement caching in API layer itself or extend it with a context API

Comment: Yeah, I implemented the caching in the api layer! THX dude!

Comment: @ChandraKumar I personally don't like the hook part. I mean, the purpose of your hook is not to "fetch users", it is just a function that calls the "fetcher" callback with the given options, and not a "users fetcher". It feels like there is some overlap of concepts (or it is just very generic).

Comment: Abstraction is great, but it can sometimes make your code not as readable as it could be if it were broken up into small parts (modules).

Comment: @VictorMolina that's what I did in the first method.